# Configuring asset picker for anonymous user

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, anonymous-authentication, asseturlselector

I am creating a public facing web site and part of the project is to allow user to pick excel file from document library for some data calculation.

But the problem is whenever some anonymous user provides explicit link then the system works but if they click on **Browse** (Asset picker is configured for the button) they face one 403 forbidden error for

> http://< site name >/_layouts/15/AssetPortalBrowser.aspx

Is there any way to provide anonymous user permission for AssetProtalBrowser?

I have already provided 'Entire web site' privilege to anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you ever found an answer but I did work on this myself for a few weeks and found a way that I thought I would share in case you or anyone else are facing this problem.

There is two parts:

1. You'll need to edit the AssetPortalBrowser.aspx to allow anonymous access.

   Find `<asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection" runat="server">`...`</script>`

   Add

   `protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess
   {
   get
   {
       return true;
   }
   }`
2. Deactivate **Limited-access user permission lockdown mode**

Now once you browse to the page with the asset picker you the sigin pop up won't come up when clicking on the browse. However you will still get the 403 if you just directly browse to the http://< site name >/_layouts/15/AssetPortalBrowser.aspx as that is missing query strings.

> Note: With **Limited-access user permission lockdown mode** deactivated, all system pages that allows anonymous access will now be available i.e. http://< site name >/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx.

I used an http handler to redirect a user if they were into the viewlsts page via the public website url. If anyone knows of a better solution than this I am up for suggestions. But from my trials/research you need Limited-access user permission lockdown mode deactivated to access the document library view.